# Google My Business | Can one GMB account publish to multiple topics?

Tags: webhooks, google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api

I need a GMB account to publish notifications to more than one topic.

Reason: A company (which I do not work with) and my own company both need to receive notifications from the same GMB account.

The issue is that the GMB API seems to allow a GMB account to publish to only a single topic.

See here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Notifications

"There will be only one notification settings resource per-account."

This is the GMB endpoint for subscribing a topic to receive notifications from an account:

`PUT` `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/<ACCOUNT ID>/notifications`

Body:

```
{
    "topicName": "<TOPIC NAME>",
    "notificationTypes": [
        "NEW_REVIEW"
    ]
}
```

However, this request simply removes the account's existing notification settings. There seems to be no way to request notifications for multiple topics.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need multiple topics? A cloud-pubsub topic can have multiple subscriptions, each of which will recieve a copy of every message published to the topic.

See https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#publisher-subscriber-relationships for a diagram.

Comment: Hi Toby. Thanks for the info. I need multiple topics because 1. The existing topic is owned by another organization. I do not have the permissions to create a subscription to it. 2. Even if I could subscribe to the existing topic, it seems illogical to rely on it. The other topic may change in name or it may be closed.